# how to properly JQuery AJAX login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to use JQuery's validation plugin to execute an AJAX login where the page doesn't have to refresh, and after hours of trial & error as well as futile efforts in searching the web, I've decided to ask some SO experts. Here is my JS logic at the moment:

```
$(formEl).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    password: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    email: {
      required: 'Please enter your email address.'
    },
    password: {
      required: 'Please enter your password.'
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
        url: form.action,
        type: form.method,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function(form) {
            // submit form
        },
        error: function() {
          // add custom jQuery validation error message stating a failure
        }

    });
  }
});

formEl.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

});
```

and server-side logic (PHP) :

```
if($validation->passes()) {
 // log user in 
}else {
// echo response??
}
```

What I want to accomplish is if the form is valid, post it to my php script and login happily, however if not, I want the page to NOT RELOAD and throw a custom jQuery validation error message under one of my inputs. So should i echo a message in my `else` clause that will travel back to the `submitHandler`? **Suggestions please !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, you should send a `json` response from `else` and then process that in `success` callback and show appropriate error on the form.

**Edit**

php code will change like this :

```
if($validation->passes()) {
// log user in 
   $data = /** whatever you're serializing **/; // include "status" for successful login
}else {
 $data = /** whatever you're serializing **/; // include "status" for error
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
return json_encode($data);
```

in ajax you change `success` like this

```
 success: function(data) {
        var status = data.status;
      // do things depending on status
    },
```

Comment: can you provide an example of how that logic should look within an answer? using the code in my question of course.

Comment: Edited my answer, please check.